# Criar define para variável de 16 bits composta por duas de 8 bits

Tags: c, bitwise

Gostaria de saber se existe algum modo de criar um define para uma "variável" em C que tenha 16 bits chamada `PORTAB`, de tal modo que escrever:

```
PORTAB = 0xAAFF;
```

Seja equivalente à:

```
PORTA = 0xAA;
PORTB = 0xFF;
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define PORTA (0xAA)
#define PORTB (0xFF)
#define PORTAB (((PORTA) << 8) | (PORTB))
```

Ou então:

```
#define JUNTAR_16_BITS(a, b) (((a) << 8) | (b))

#define PORTA (0xAA)
#define PORTB (0xFF)
#define PORTAB JUNTAR_16_BITS(PORTA, PORTB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você use duas `macros` diferentes, uma para leitura e outra para gravação.

**Leitura:**

```
#define PORTAB ((unsigned short)(((PORTA) << 8) | (PORTB)))
```

**Gravação:**

```
#define PORTAB( value ) do{ unsigned short v = value; PORTA = ((unsigned char*)&v)[1]; PORTB = ((unsigned char*)&v)[0]; }while(0)
```

**Exemplo de Uso:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PORTAB ((unsigned short)(((PORTA) << 8) | (PORTB)))

#define SET_PORTAB( value ) do{ unsigned short v = value; PORTA = ((unsigned char*)&v)[1]; PORTB = ((unsigned char*)&v)[0]; }while(0)

int main( void )
{
    /* Gravação */

    PORTA = 0xAA;
    PORTB = 0xFF;

    SET_PORTAB( 0xAAFF );

    /* Leitura */

    printf( "PORTA  = 0x%X\n", PORTA );
    printf( "PORTB  = 0x%X\n", PORTB );
    printf( "PORTAB = 0x%X\n", PORTAB );

    return 0;
}
```